# Convert variable stored in AsyncStorage then state to Number

Tags: react-native, expo

How can I convert an AsyncStorage stored number (stored as a string) to a Number in react native (I am using Expo).

It works converting the string to a number like this:

```
myNum = Number('3'); // THIS WORKS
```

But this does not work:

```
myNum = Number(this.state.myStateNum); // This does not work, returns zero

myNum = Math.floor(this.state.myStateNum); // This does not work, returns zero
```

I am getting my variable from AsyncStorage and then storing as a state but I can't figure out why I can't convert it to a number.

If it helps this is how I set using async:

```
async function setItem(key, value) {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
    console.log(key, value);
    return value;
  } catch (error) {
  }
}

setVar = setItem('myStateNum', '3');
```

This is how I get using async:

```
async componentWillMount() {
  const myStateNumGet = await AsyncStorage.getItem('myStateNum');
  if (myStateNumGet) {
    this.setState({ myStateNum: myStateNumGet });
  } else {
    this.setState({ myStateNum: false });
  }
}
```

Any suggestions/help would be great.

Comment: See if you are getting a number from AsyncStorage.getItem, console it before you use setState. Seems like the else statement is working.

Comment: I originally thought the same but the variable is being passed as a string when I call: `this.state.myStateNum`

Comment: It will be a string, what is the value of `this.state.myStateNum` before you pass it to `parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
myNum = parseInt(this.state.myStateNum);
```

You can try other methods too, but the above should work for you...
https://coderwall.com/p/5tlhmw/converting-strings-to-number-in-javascript-pitfalls

Comment: This return: `NaN`

Comment: what is the raw value of `this.state.myStateNum`? It must not be something that can be converted to a number then. See the [MSN docs for parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) which states "The parseInt function converts its first argument to a string, parses it, and returns an integer or NaN."

Comment: I added: `console.log(typeof myStateNumGet);` and console log shows it as a `string`

Comment: This is the first you've mentioned `myStateNumGet` so for the sake of this discussion, I'm going to assume it's the same as `this.state.myStateNum`. It doesn't matter if it's a typeof string. `typeof '3'` and `typeof 'somestring'` will both return the type of string. But only the first can be coerced to a number. In other words `parseInt('3') => 3` while `parseInt('somestring') => NaN`

Comment: Ah, I see `myStateNumbGet` is the value returned from AsyncStorage. console.log() that before you hit the if statement and see what the value of it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `ASyncStorage.getItem()` returns a Promise object, not the string that you are expecting.

You can find some more info about that here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/asyncstorage.html

In terms of your problem, i'd structure your code to accept a callback to getItem, that way you can ensure a returned value before you do your computation. The code would look something like this.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("myStateNum").then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    this.setState({myStateEnum: result});
}).done();
```

You could also try using `.value` to get your result, eg `let myStateNum = result.value`. Am fairly rusty on the subject but these methods should be able to help you

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is a duplicate of the question here https://forums.expo.io/t/convert-variable-stored-in-asyncstorage-then-state-to-number/3430